# Sitefinity MVC: How to get the content item Url in Detail view of the widget template

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sitefinity

I have a custom module with custom List and Detail widget templates. In my List widget template, I can get the content Item url with this:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Items)
{
 var navigateUrl = HyperLinkHelpers.GetDetailPageUrl(item, ViewBag.DetailsPageId, ViewBag.OpenInSamePage, Model.UrlKeyPrefix); 
}
```

and then:

```
<a href="@navigateUrl">
```

Why can't I do the same thing in my Detail widget template and get the full content Item url? Is there a different method to get the full Url of the page in Detail widget template in MVC?

I am getting these build errors:

CS1061  'ContentDetailsViewModel' does not contain a definition for 'Items' and no accessible extension method 'Items' accepting a first argument of type 'ContentDetailsViewModel' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

CS1061  'ContentDetailsViewModel' does not contain a definition for 'UrlKeyPrefix' and no accessible extension method 'UrlKeyPrefix' accepting a first argument of type 'ContentDetailsViewModel' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

CS0103  The name 'navigateUrl' does not exist in the current context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if you need to implement yourself, use one of the overloads
https://github.com/Sitefinity/feather/blob/8c0bcde57c27322d48084485694f32e0714d15ee/Telerik.Sitefinity.Frontend/Mvc/Helpers/HyperLinkHelpers.cs#L32

What's the usecase though, you need the current url, or it's like for a related content section or something?

Sidenote, you can browse the code over here

https://github.com/Sitefinity/feather-widgets
https://github.com/Sitefinity/feather
https://github.com/Sitefinity/feather-packages

Comment: Hi Steve, thank you, I'll check these out. I am trying to built social share icons with the content item's title and url, pre-populated in the code in my Detail page.